# Second time creating ui elements will be invisible

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt-creator, qpushbutton

I have a vector.

```
QVector<QPushButton*> buttonVector;
```

With this function I add dynamically buttons to the UI.

```
void MainWindow::createButton()
{
  for(int x = 0; x < list.length(); x++)
  {
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this);
    button->setText(QString::number(list.at(x)->ID()));
    button->setGeometry(x_cor,y_cor,50,50);
    //button->setVisible(true);
    buttonVector.append(button);
  }
}
```

At the start of my program this function triggers and works perfectly, every button is showing.

But after I recreate every button with this function after I press a button, they are all invisible if I don't add the line:

```
button->setVisible(true);
```

Why is that? At the beginning they are all visible without this line.

Comment: I have not seen this behavior. Also you may want to use a layout.

Comment: It was a prototype but thank you, I completely forget about layouts. Is this a bug only on my side? Or is this "normal"?

Comment: I don't believe it is normal or expected behavior. And I create a lot of dynamic widgets in my applications.